# Is there a mistake in my switch case function?

Tags: javascript

```
let broj = document.querySelector("#broj");
let div = document.querySelector("#odgovor");

function brojdana() {
    switch (parseInt(broj.value)) {
        case 1:
            div.innerHTML = "Mesec ima 31 dan.";
            break;

        case 2:
            div.innerHTML = "Mesec ima 28 dana.";
            break;

        case 4:
            div.innerHTML = "Mesec ima 30 dana.";
            break;
        default:
            div.innerHTML = "Ovde ima jedna greska.";
    }
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any obvious mistake. What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: Please tell us what mistake you experience (and what steps you have taken to mitigate them)

Comment: Not so much a mistake, but: don't use `.innerHTML` if you're setting text. Use `.textContent`.

Comment: Do you expect `1` to be January of February, because it is February...

Comment: Case 1 is for January, case 2 for February, and case 4 is for April.

Comment: Well there is your problem: `new Date('01/21/2022').getMonth()` results in `0`

Comment: @Akxe There's no `Date` in the code. The month value comes from an input field